# Creating global variables using JavaScript for QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, stateless, stateful

I'm having an issue with QML/JS integration.

I have a javascript list variable stored in a .js file. I want to write to this variable from one QML file, and read it from another QML file. I cannot seem to find a solution to this. I've over-simplified my actual code to make it comprehensible!

```
// writeValue.QML
import "../javascript/storedValue.js" as StoredValue
...
MouseArea{
    onClicked{
        StoredValue.value.push(1)
    }
}

// readValue.QML
import "../javascript/storedValue.js" as StoredValue
...
Text{
    text : StoredValue.value
}

//storedValue.js
var value = []
```

I have tried using '.pragma library' and not using it, to no avail.

What happens is the writeValue.QML writes successfully, so [1, 1, ,1, ...]. Whereas readValue.QML just finds an empty list, [].

Answer (score 6):

Just put `.pragma library` at  the beginning of the JS file. In this way, there will be only *one instance* imported by QML components.

Remember however that no update signal is issued when a `var` property changes. If you want to have global `var` with update support, you should export a custom `QObject` via `setContextProperty()` on the C++ side.